# Actions needed for app when waking from sleep on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a graphics application that occasionally displays incorrectly after a sleep / wake cycle.
I'm wondering if there is something I should do on the Sleep or Wake events. I'm capturing these events already, because I hide the cursor in the app, and when the app wakes the cursor appears and has to be re-hidden. I'm creating my images with  [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc ]initWithBitmapDataPlanes:outplanes, doing lots of bit manipulation on multiple images. I display the image full screen. Xcode 7.1, OSX 10.10
The error I get is a shimmering on the display as if my merge routines are using the wrong data.
I was assuming the sleep took a snapshot of all my data, including whatever is on the stack? It's hard to reproduce the problem, but my App is going to be running every day in a public space and uses the scheduler to sleep each night and autowake in the morning.
Should I reinitialise all my variables on a wake?
I can't see anything on the apple docs about actions you should take on these events.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to worry about this.  If it is, that is likely to be either a bug in your app, or a bug in Apple's code.  Indeed, the cursor issue you mention sounds like a bug to me, and you should log a bug in Apple's bug reporter about that.  Sleep/wake should be entirely transparent for apps that don't have a specific reason to care.  You will need to try to pin down the issue you are seeing, somehow, and diagnose it.